# USB Drive not working with Windows 7. Works on Linux and Windows 8/8.1

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, usb-flash-drive

I have a USB thumb drive (PNY 128GB) that works fine with Windows 8/8.1 and with Linux, but does not work on Windows 7. Doesn't show up at all. I have tried formatting it in both Win8 and Linux (Ubuntu) in NTFS, exFAT, and FAT32. No Luck.

Comment: Could you add some information about the partition table (MBR or GPT)? It would also be helpful to know if you tried different computers/USB-ports to make sure it is not a hardware (or controller) problem.

Comment: It is MBR. I have tried in in all USB ports on several Win7 machines, it doesn't show up at all. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I know you said that it doesn't show on Win7 at all, but just to be thorough, you have checked that it isn't showing in Disk Management, and not just that it isn't showing in the system tray? To find out, press Windows Key + R, type diskmgmt.msc into the Run dialog, and press Enter.

Comment: Doesn't show up in Disk Management. The computer doesn't recognize it in any way, shape, or form.